# Passing vendor ID through URL via a link for each vendor

Tags: php, mysql, url, get

I am trying to pass a vendor ID through a url. Each vendor should have a link called "rate this vendor" that when clicked brings you to a rate_vendor_add page with that particular vendor chosen in the drop down box. I am using a php generator program. Support told me to add the following code. It is pulling the vendor id but it is not a hyperlink. Can anyone see anything wrong with this code? There is an image of where he said this code goes and an image of what now shows in the column that is supposed to display a link to the rate vendor page.

```
$value = "< a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?vendorid=" . $data["ID"] . "'Rate this vendor</a>";
```

[view as link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw9A1.png)

[rate vendor link is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw9A1.png)

Comment: can you please post the page code in your question? complete code of the table you are creating through php. It's unclear how you are writing and what is exactly not working. Please post code to make your question clear.

Comment: replace your code with `<a href="vendor_ratings_add.php?vendorid=<?php echo $data['ID'];?>">Rate this vendor</a>` and check worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tag is not closed.

Try this:

```
$value = "<a href='vendor_ratings_add.php?vendorid=" . $data["ID"] . "'>Rate this vendor</a>";
```